# Eclipse only shows random red markers / No red markers on syntax errors

Tags: java, eclipse, markers

Hello I have a weird problem with eclipse. 
When I tried to call an unimplemented method (because I wanted to implement it right after that) eclipse didn't mark it as an error. Then I tried some other stuff trying to force a syntax error. It's not like it doesn't mark anything at all but it seems really random and my errors are still not marked.

[image]

[image]

I cleaned the project and restarted eclipse several times and checked my build path : 
[image]

And nothing works - Anything ever encountered a similar problem ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the computer?

Comment: @litelite I did now - still the same results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I solved it myself - feeling pretty stupid now.
Apparently I had a minor error in the head of my method (two commas inbetween parameters) and i thought the method head was marked red because of the syntax errors that are actually marked red in the picture. 
When I removed the second comme, suddenly all the red marks appeared and the errors were found.